# Loss of height rate in a half sphere?

Tags: derivatives, applications

The question:
A flask with a shape of half of a sphere with 5 meters as its radius is said to be fully filled, the flask has a hole at the bottom spot. If the hole were to be opened with the volume loss rate of $0.125m^3/minute$ How much is the height loss rate when the water is 4 meters from below?

From what I see in the problem, $\frac{dV}{dt} = 0.125m^3/minute$
and what we are trying to find is $\frac{dh}{dt}$
which means we need to find $\frac{dV}{dh}$ so we can multiply it like this $\frac{dh}{dV} * \frac{dV}{dt} = \frac{dh}{dt}$ but then I can't seem to find a way to derivate the half sphere volume formula ($\frac{2}{3}πr^3$) against h to make $\frac{dV}{dh}$

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the hemisphere oriented with the flat part upwards?

Comment: @Arthur yes, like a bowl

Comment: @Arthur The question I'm asking is only allowed to be answered with derivatives

Comment: Can you find the volume of the water in the flask as a function of the height of water in the flask?  Note that once the water dips below the 5-meter mark, it's not in the shape of a hemisphere anymore so you can't use the hemisphere volume formula.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang that is where I'm stuck, I can't seem to find a way to substitute the radius with a height equation

Comment: @MatthewLeingang That's much more complicated than it needs to be. That function isn't nice, or easy to find, _especially_ without integration. See my hint below for the easy way to avoid (most of) said function.

Comment: @Arthur: You're right.  I've already solved the problem; just trying to help OP with figuring it out.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: At any stage, $R^2 = r^2+ (R-h)^2$ where $R$ is the initial radius, $r$ is the new radius and $h$ is the height of the water from the hole.[image]

Comment: If I were to substitute the radius with that in the volume formula, then I would be able to derivate it against h, but then what do I put in as the R?

Comment: R is the initial radius which you said was 5 meters

Comment: I should have said the smaller r then, do I just replace it as 1?

Comment: You can even derivate this formula directly wrt $h$ to get $\frac {dr}{dh}$.

Comment: What do you mean? Aren’t you replacing $r$ in the volume formula using the above relation? You’ll get the volume as a function solely of $h$ .

Comment: If I were to derivate the given formula, then wouldn't it be $\frac{dR}{dh}$ instead of small r?

Comment: $\frac{dR}{dh}=0$ because $R$ is constant.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: As far as the velocity of the surface is concerned, at any fixed point in time it is irrelevant that the walls of the container are slanted. It only matters how large the surface is.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

2D problem.

Consider a circle radius $r$ , centre $(0,r)$.

$x^2+(y-r)^2=r^2$;

$y=r \pm \sqrt{r^2-x^2}$;

Let $x \ge 0$.

Choose $y=r-\sqrt{r^2-x^2}.$

Volume of revolution when rotated about $y-$axis.

$dV = πx^2dy;$

Integrate from  $0$ to $h$, which gives $V(h)$, the cap.

Try to finish.